# Reading string from raw txt file

Tags: java, android, string, java.util.scanner

I have a raw txt file with delimiters which i use to split text. To receive text I use scanner:

```
int textid = getResources().getIdentifier(word, null, this.getPackageName());
            Scanner ch = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(textid));
```

Opened file is correct. When I begin receiving information I need to read it until "$" is got.

```
            while (ch.hasNext()) {
                    str = ch.next();
                    boolean flag = (str.equals("$"));
                    while (!(str.equals("$"))) {
                        str = ch.next();
                    }
```

The problem is that when str equals "$" (Checked it through breakpoint) flag equals "false". However, if I initialize String m = "$" and check `flag = m.equals("$")`flag equals "true". Also tried to use `str != "$"` but it didn't help.
My guess is that scanner.next() returns another type but it seems to be rather strange.

Comment: Does the `"$"` appear as an isolated word (i.e. the characters before and after it are whitespaces)? The `next` method reads a string up to the next whitespace character.

Comment: Yes, an isolated word. I checked it in debugger, shown symbol is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

First next() reads multiple characters until whitespace is found.

Go through every char in str to see if its the '$'. Then when you find it do whatever you wanted to do.

```
while (ch.hasNext()) {
        String str = ch.next();
        for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i) == '$') {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, the problem was that first read string in the file consisted of 2 chars: \ufeff (symbol of the beginning of the file) and "$". Besides, first char wasn't seen, so the string looked like just "$". To read "$" should write str.charAt(1). Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 0):

When your code reads a `"$"`, it will break the inner loop. When it starts over the outer loop, you're calling `ch.next()` again, which overwrites the previous `"$"`in `str`. This might be the reason why `flag` is set to `false`. It would detect the `"$"` only if it's the first thing in the file.

Also, you might want to check `ch.hasNext()` in the inner loop again.